# Clion shortcut to move up and down "switcher"

Tags: intellij-idea, clion, shortcut

clion has a shortcut to move between targets in the switcher up and down. I want to change to move down `control tab` to `option j` and up `control shift tab` to `option k` . But I can only add one shortcut to the move down. How can I change the shortcut move up.
I attach a photo as it was [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgExv.png) and how [I did it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRuSS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known limitation](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177432), feel free to vote.

Comment: Not at the moment.